# Функциональные компоненты, которые могут входить в определение класса C#

Tags: c#, синтаксис

В билете есть такой вопрос: "Назовите функциональные компоненты, которые могут входить в определение класса в контексте языка C#, поясните их назначение, приведите примеры реализации."

Можете ли Вы подсказать, что за **компоненты, которые могут входить в определение класса**? Назовите несколько, дальше я сам всё прочту и вспомню.

Comment: эм, методы, свойства, конструктор, финализатор, поля, события?

Comment: "компоненты, которые могут входить в определение класса" - эта фраза для Вас вообще никакой смысловой нагрузки не несет? Что Вы делали весь семестр? Попросите другой билет.

Comment: Эту тему не изучали, поэтому спрашиваю. Экзамен должен быть зимой, но так получилось, что пару закрыли раньше чем надо и экзамен в июле. Будьте добры и помогите. Я же не прошу так детально написать, просто лишь назвать один или два компоненты.

Comment: @tym32167 уже написал

Comment: Ок, спасибо @tym32167

Answer (score 4):

Эм.. У слова "функциональные" тут может быть два значения.

В первом случае предполагается просто "несущие какие-либо функции", т. е. все составляющие класса - конструктор, методы, поля, свойства, события и остальное.

Другой возможный смысл (хотя и более маловероятный) - "нечто, присущее функциональному программированию". Функциональному программированию чуждо состояние, там преимущественно используются чистые функции. Довольно странно их делать инстансными, поэтому они, скорее всего, будут представлены статическими методами. Возможно ещё сюда расширяющие методы отнести. И data-классы с конструктором и деконструктором `Deconstruct` (не путать с деструктором!).

Пожалуй, это всё, что приходит в голову после прочтения вопроса.